# Defining ASP.NET SOAP web service response

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

Apologies if this is an amatuer question. I have to modify an existing ASMX web service. The problem is, I need to modify the response that the web service generates. Below is an example of the current response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" mlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <InsertCaseShortResponse xmlns="http://website.com/Service/">
      <InsertCaseShortResult>50314</InsertCaseShortResult>
    </InsertCaseShortResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The InsertCaseShortResult returns a unique reference number if successful or an error message in case of failure. What I need to do, is add another response tag which gives a true or false flag as to whether the insert was a success or not. I haven't been able to find much info anywhere about how web services responses are constructed, I think I'm missing a fundamental element here.

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you've got the WSDL it's a good start point. After that, knowing how's the webservice is deployed is mandatory, legacy in this scenario has very little meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by "legacy" you mean ASMX web services.

Based on your WSDL, you seem to have something like this in your web service server-side code:

```
[WebMethod]
public int InsertCaseShort(/* params here */)
{
    int result;

    /* Code here */

    return result;
}
```

To add an additional field, you will need to return a class reference instead of an integer value.

**Example:**

```
public class InsertCaseShortResult
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public bool Successful { get; set; }
}
```

And in your WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public InsertCaseShortResult InsertCaseShort(/* params here */)
{
    var result = new InsertCaseShortResult();

    /* Code here */

    return result;
}
```

Feel free to ask any additional questions.

Comment: Ah I see. So the format of the response is dependant on the return type of the web method? Thank you very much, that was extremely helpful :)

Comment: And yes I was referring to an ASMX web service. I edited my original question to clarify for anyone else